# Please add year to dates in previous year

Tags: feature-request, dates

I know this has been discussed many times, firstly as the initial [existence for a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates) was passed.  Then it was reduced to maybe [11 or 10 months ago before years were added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15576/add-year-to-dates-for-dates-within-11-months), I'd like to request that this is solved once and for all by the following rules

On *1st January* of each year Dates up to *1st October of previous year* get a year added.

eg.  at midnight on 1st January 2014,

- 13 April becomes 13 April 2013
- 26 September becomes - 26 September 2013.
- 12 December remains 12 December

On *1st February* of each year **all dates** in previous year get a year added.

I think this would remove all confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375078/282094)

Answer (score 2):

The current rules are that the year is displayed if it is not the same as the current year. This is simple, consistent, and not too confusing. What's wrong with the current system?

Your proposal seems similar to [Introduce the new year gradually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161066/introduce-the-new-year-gradually) (see answers there)

Comment: The current system is really confusing.  I look at a date without a year and I think this year but when I look again I see its for July last year which is a long time ago.  The heuristic we all have in our heads is that no year means this year.  If this is not possible then perhaps years should be displayed on every date which would **actually** be consistent and not too confusing.  I find the current system inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: @TobyAllen: No, in the current system, "a date without a year". Is this year. If the system was how you say it is, then [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161066/introduce-the-new-year-gradually) would never have been asked. Give me an example of where the year isn't provided and it's not this year.

Comment: Years don't show up in the [activity tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth?tab=activity&sort=comments&page=93), that's about it I think. There was a feature request somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Well I was looking at one this morning which is why I asked the question . Ill see if I can find it or if it was in the activity tab.

Comment: Note that this rule is true for posts, but not everywhere. Like today, the badge pages [(still) use a different rule](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221655/how-come-the-year-doesnt-show-here).