# Timestamp on "others with this badge" page

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center

I'm looking at the pages that show "others with this badge", such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/192/datetime):

[image: screenshot]

- The time of day is of very little usefulness, and could probably be removed.
- The year is missing in some cases, and present in others such as `'12`.   This feels weird.  I thought it was just omited for the current year, but here it shows December of 2013 without an `'13`.
- It would be much cleaner in all cases if it just showed in `dd MMM yyyy` format, such as:

  "Awarded 22 May 2014 to"

Just a suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: On any date up to a little over a year ago, the year is not displayed. This is the case with all date displays on the site, IIRC.

Comment: Related: [Please add year to dates in previous year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171291)

Comment: So all timestamps are formatted the same regardless of context?  That seems like the wrong thing to do.  What value is showing the time of day on this page?