# Show year in SEDE timestamps from previous year

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, dates

Can we adjust the display behaviour of timestamps in SEDE so that it matches the general Stack Exchange behaviour (better)? On Stack Exchange, the year is shown if an action (post creation, latest post edit) took place [in another year than the current one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171295/295232). SEDE still has the old behaviour where the year is shown only if the timestamp was more than a year ago.

I just visited [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/975140/revisions-by-user-and-keyword?Keyword=Android&UserId=2675672) which, if you interpret the timestamps as displayed, was last edited a month *before* it was posted:

[image]

The timestamps on Q&A sites show the time as well; that isn't strictly necessary for me, but I'd really like to have that **mar 11** changed to **mar 11 '18**.

Comment: (I'm aware of @rene's time travel capabilities - hovering over the timestamp indicates that he hasn't used his powers this time.)

Comment: [This method](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/df52cec7183fdcaa221e51110bb7e033019a837e/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/ExtensionMethods.cs#L275) determines if  a year is shown. The cutoff is 330 days.

Comment: Hover doesn't work on mobile on SE sites, though it does work on many other sites; I think it's the JS library.