# Mentioning year in the Questions tab of users

Tags: feature-request, questions, profile-page, tabs

In the answers tab, the years(last and before) are mentioned, but in the Questions tab of **users** (not the Questions tab below the Home tab) , the year is mentioned only when the **difference is 11 months**.

For example if a question was asked/ has last activity in or before **Feb 2020** it shows`MM DD'YY at hh:mm <username> rep`.
But if it were asked later, it only shows the month and date, but the year isn't specified.

[image]

This is also observed in the Similar questions section while asking a new question.

[image]

So can the year be added in the Questions tab of the Users if it had last activity in the last year irrespective of the month in which it was asked?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171291/please-add-year-to-dates-in-previous-year